# vbnet Webbrowser click button and get page adress or open same page

Tags: vb.net

i have theese code for click a button on page

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
        'MsgBox(element.GetAttribute("className"))
        If element.GetAttribute("className") = "csc-button csc-button--popup" Then
            element.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

But when i click the button opening a page on internet explorer
Can i open this page on webbrowser or can i get adress of page?

Thanks

Comment: `Private Sub WB1_NewWindow(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WB1.NewWindow
    newUrl = WB1.Url.ToString

    e.Cancel = True
    WB1.Navigate(newUrl)
End Sub`

İ find this answer but not working for me

Comment: or this code not worked

`  e.Cancel = true;
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(WebBrowser1.StatusText)`